# How do I programmatically authenticate a user in quarkus when reading from an inbound topic?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, quarkus, quarkus-reactive, smallrye-reactive-messaging

Okay, I admit this is a bit of a weird question. But we are in the process of moving our application from SpringBoot to Quarkus. So far, so good until I came upon this little problem.

In Spring, we have an InputChannelInterceptor which pulls out a custom header value from all messages in Kafka. This header value contains an access token, which we can then use to authenticate the user. Specifically, we `@Autowire` our authentication provider, which takes that token and returns a `Principal`. Then you can call Spring's `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(...)` to set the principal for the remainder of the processing context.

I need to do something like this in Quarkus. So I have an interceptor already written, which pulls the access token out of the Kafka message. But I don't know how to do the actual authentication, nor how to establish the authorized user in the security context. Quarkus has a `SecurityContext` class, which is available for `@Inject`, but it has no mechanism that I can find to set the user, only retrieve the user.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: This is a possible sequence assuming `quarkus-smallrye-jwt` is used to verify the token: 1. Inject `io.quarkus.security.identity.IdentityProviderManager` and request `SecurityIdentity`, passing it an instance of `new TokenAuthenticationRequest(new JsonWebTokenCredential(token))` 2. Inject `CurrentIdentityAssociation` and set `SecurityIdentity` obtained in the step 1: `association.setIdentity(identiy)`. We should simplify it similarly to how a non-HTTP-centric protocol security such as GRPC is supported in Quarkus (note I'm about to go on PTO, will reply afterwards, thanks)